# Cocos3d: no textures on iPad

Tags: ipad, cocos3d

I'm making a 3D model viewer. I have problem with one of the models: on simulator everything's ok, but on device textures are gone.

Simulator: http://i.imgur.com/1nh5r.png

Device: http://i.imgur.com/N1cK3.png

I converted this model from .dae to .pod using PVRGeoPod plugin for Maya. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

No idea, but an advice: create the simplest possible 3D model (a cube) with a texture and run it through the same process. The texture should ideally be small and have power of two dimensions, ie 64x64.

If this still shows no textures on iPad, you know that somewhere this process is broken. If the cube does look fine, you know that the problem is with the model. From the looks of it, it could simply be too complex, or the texture may be too large or has to be a power of two dimension (iPad should support NPOT textures though).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is with the path of the images you use when you are creating the texture. Where are you storing the images? And how do you acquire the path? On iPad you should always store only the filenames and ask the path for it from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be file name. I'm just guessing, consider that iOS simulator is case insensitive but Devices are working with case sensitive.